# does Windows System Restore bring back uninstalled programs?

Tags: windows, uninstall, system-restore

Does Windows System Restore bring back uninstalled programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing [this article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/160858/what_exactly_does_system_restore_back_up.html)'s fourth and fifth paragraph, I would say it's possible, but unlikely to be successful. I have not done any practical tests to this effect though.

Comment: Read the fourth and fifth paragraphs.

Comment: Heh, I guess I should really read the entire article before I cite it :D Edited.